# Migrating from Angular 5 to Angular 6 i got these error TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected

Tags: angular, typescript, apollo, apollo-client, angular6

These code was workig ok in Angular 5 but when migrating to Angular 6 I got the error message:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: You provided an invalid
>   object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable,
>   Promise, Array, or Iterable.
>       TypeError: You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
>           at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:41)
>           at from (from.js:17)
>           at new QueryRef (QueryRef.js:6)
>           at Apollo.push../node_modules/apollo-angular/Apollo.js.ApolloBase.watchQuery
>   (Apollo.js:29)
>           at contacts.service.ts:75

[Here is the code](https://github.com/yamenmarquez/OeeApp/blob/master/frontend/src/app/main/content/oee-backend/contacts/contacts.service.ts)

I would really appreciate some indication of what could be generating this error

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same error. <s>I fixed it by replacing my usages of `watchQuery` with just `query`.</s>

Example old code:

```
return this.apollo
  .watchQuery<GetPartnerCollectionsQuery>({
    query: getPartnerCollectionsQuery,
    variables,
  })
  .valueChanges.pipe(
    map(result => {
      return result.data.getPartnerCollections.collections;
    })
  );
```

Example new code:

```
return this.apollo
  .query<GetPartnerCollectionsQuery>({
    query: getPartnerCollectionsQuery,
    variables,
  })
  .pipe(
    map(result => {
      return result.data.getPartnerCollections.collections;
    })
  );
```

Kind of bizarre that `watchQuery` doesn't seem to work anymore since it seems to be the "correct" kind of query, but hopefully this is just a temporary bug.

**Edit:** Just tracked down the official ticket for this bug:

https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-angular/issues/545

**Edit 2:**: Found official solution, update your packages to new versions that fix this bug:

```
"apollo-angular": "^1.1.0-rc.0",
"apollo-angular-link-http": "^1.1.0-rc.0",
```